# Power BI M Query to conditionally concatenate rows

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am using Power BI Desktop and I have a scenario with some rather poorly 'structured' data that I need a little help cleaning up. The data looks like this:

```
Address | 123 Whatever Street  <br/>
| Some Suburb| Some State  <br/>
| Postcode  <br/>
| Country  <br/>
Company | Company Name Goes Here  <br/>
Details | Freeform text goes here  <br/>
| and more freeform text here  <br/>
```

and so on till the end of the data set.

The desired outcome is to concatenate the rows that start with the "|" (pipe) onto the end of the prior row(s) that start without a "|" symbol.

For Example the output above would look like this:

```
Address | 123 Whatever Street | Some Suburb| Some State | Postcode | Country  <br/>
Company | Company Name Goes Here  <br/>
Details | Freeform text goes here | and more freeform text here  <br/>
```

All the data is in a single column.

I am not quite sure how to approach this outside of knowing that the condition of a "|" symbol means that the data belongs to the preceding row(s). I thought about creating a 'group identifier' like a counter that increments only when there is no "|" at the start of a row, but cannot seem to get anything working.

I need to be able to perform the data manipulation as a step or set of steps in the Query Editor, using M Query.

Comment: Looks like you just need to replace `<br/>{carriage return} |` with `|` Similiar to this https://www.howtoexcel.org/power-query/bulk-replace-values/ _but_ you need to find replace across the entire input file, not just a particular column. I'm not sure if M can do this.

Comment: Perhaps initially you could experiment by manually find / replace the values in something like Visual Studio code to confirm it does what you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click your data column > Replace Values > replace " " [space] with nothing

Add an Index column.  Add Column > Index Column > From 1 or From 0, it doesn't matter.

Select the Index column > right-click > Replace Values > replace 888 with 999.  That will generate this code in the formula bar:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Added Index",888,999,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Index"})
```

Replace that code with this code:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Added Index",each [Index],each if Text.StartsWith([data],"|") then null else [Index],Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Index"})
```

- Select the Index column > right-click > Fill > Down
- Select the Index column > right-click > Group By
- New Column name = "Merged", Operation = Sum, Column = Column1 (data column header)

You should have a new column that is errored out.  Replace this formula:

```
= Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Index"}, {{"Merged", each List.Sum([data]), type nullable text}})
```

With this formula:

```
= Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Index"}, {{"Merged", each Text.Combine([data],"|"), type nullable text}})
```

- Select the Merged column > right-click > Replace Values > replace || with |
- Select the Merged column > right-click > Split Column > By Delimiter > use a | delimiter and make sure "At every occurrence" is selected.
- Delete the Index column
- Select all columns > Merge Columns > use | delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an M query, it's a Powershell script.

I adapted some code from here: https://mcpmag.com/articles/2018/08/08/replace-text-with-powershell.aspx

```
((Get-Content -path C:\SourceFile.txt -Raw) -replace ' </br>`r`n| ','|') | Set-Content -Path C:\OutputFile.txt
```

This should fix your file as required then you can import more easily into M

Have I said yet that that file format is dopey? :D I guess some kind of HTML export is the only option the source system has.

Comment: Appreciate the input. This one however is actually data being extracted from PDF's (horror incarnate I know)

Comment: If you already have an automated process to extract data from a PDF then it should be pretty easy to add a step to that process that does a trivial find and replace.